# PHP allow URL include

Tags: php, security

I want to ask something regarding `allow_url_include` - ...

If a server have got `allow_url_include` enabled in the PHP configuration ... Can the server owner easily create a PHP script and do something like:

```
include("http://example.com/configuration.php");
echo $mysql['username'];
```

So he can get the value of the MySQL username?

If that was possible, can I disallow that on my script to prevent hackers?

Thank you!

Comment: No.. Its very simple No

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI - Thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, he will get the same thing as you have in your web browser. That would be a huge security issue.

Note that if your webserver is misconfigured, it can happen.

Answer (score 0):

He can't get the value of the MySQL username.

He can only get the source code and the results of the page :

```
http://example.com/configuration.php
```